# Bean property in scala for getters and setters

Tags: scala

Using Bean annotation, we get setters and getters to variables in a class.
But is a good practice in scala programming to use getters and setters like java? I am trying to know how many programmers in real world use Bean annotation in Scala.

Comment: Functional Programming (FP) discourages data structures that maintain state, so Scala style tries to avoid setters whenever possible.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: They are unnecessary, just use val or var. Getters and setters are automatically created and seamlessly used.  Java does not have this so you need to create them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Scala already automatically creates getters and setters for fields. This is because fields are never actually public. Instead, all fields are private, and a getter `def <fieldname>: <fieldtype>` is created. A setter `def <fieldname>_=(new: <fieldtype>): Unit` is created if the field is `var`. Because the getter method has no parameter lists, its usage looks like a Java field access (`obj.field`), though it isn't. Scala also introduces sugar for methods that end in `_=`, allowing them to be called with `x.y = z` notation. This is the same as `x.y_=(z)`. You can manually create methods like this and see the same behavior. (Caveat: a manually defined method `x_=` will not sugar unless a getter `x` is also present.)

The function of (`Boolean`)`BeanProperty` is to simply add aliases to these methods named in the standard Java Bean way (`getX`/`isX` and `setX`). Therefore, they are unnecessary for pure Scala, but are useful if you need to conform to the Java standard for some reason. E.g. you use some library that reflectively accesses a bean's properties.